# PowerBI Embedded not working because of X-Frame-Options

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, x-frame-options

I'm using powerbi-service-js to embed reports in my Angular 8 application. Until October 3rd, everything worked fine. I would log in to the url (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token) and then make a request to the powerbi API to get the report token. But now, when using pbiService's embed function, I get the following error. I'm using DirectQuery to construct the report and Deploying the Application in Nginx.

That's the error on Chrome console:

Refused to display 'https://app.powerbi.com/tokenRefresh?ver=1570487269987' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

ERROR DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://app.powerbi.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at e.retryTokenRefresh (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.10956.175/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:2245948)
    at e.onTokenRefreshLoad (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.10956.175/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:2245770)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.document.getElementById.onload [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYload] (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.10956.175/scripts/reportEmbed.min.js:1:2245299)

Answer (score 1):

And probably you are viewing this using Google Chrome browser? Because since the date you mentioned, [it blocks mixed content](https://www.howtogeek.com/443032/what-is-mixed-content-and-why-is-chrome-blocking-it/). So check your URLs and make sure you do not use HTTP, but all of them are HTTPS. You can confirm this theory by viewing your app in another browser.